# How do I type the skew-symmetric matrix notation. I am using overleaf and unable to find any leads. Appriciate for any help

Tags: matrices, overleaf

[image]

The notation I am looking for is circled in red above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\lfloor\cdot\rfloor\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is exactly what i was looking for.